# Update knockout viewmodel after ajax call

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel

I am having an issue saving changes back to my observable viewmodel using KnockoutJS.  To keep this simple I will just show the basics....My viewmodel has a class called EmployeeSkill, which has two properties and the EmployeeSkillsViewModel is an array that contains zero to many of these skills as shown below in my Index.cshtml page. I have a variable: ctrl which holds a reference to the input control next to the button I click to open a modal dialog which allows the user to enter an existing OR new value in its input control. When the save button is clicked the database is checked or updated and an integer value is returned.  I would like to save this returned value to my model.

The viewmodel is populated with JSON that looks like this:

[{"EmployeeSkillId": 1, "SkillsId": 999}, {"EmployeeSkillId": 2, "SkillsId": 777}, {"EmployeeSkillId": 3, "SkillsId": 888}]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ctrl;

  $(document).on("click", ".open-editSkillName", function () {
    ctrl = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input');
    $(".modal-body #edit_skill_name").val($(this).closest('.input-group').find('input').val());
  });

  $(function () {
     function EmployeeSkillsViewModel() {
       var self = this;
       self.EmployeeSkillId = ko.observable("");
       self.SkillsId = ko.observable("");

       var EmployeeSkill = {
         EmployeeSkillId: self.EmployeeSkillId,
         SkillsId: self.SkillsId,
       };

       self.EmployeeSkill = ko.observable();
       self.EmployeeSkillsArray = ko.observableArray();

       self.updateSkillName = function (ctrl) {
         var skillName = $(".modal-body #edit_skill_name").val();

         $(ctrl).val(skillName);

         // Check to see if this skill exists...
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("UpsertSkill", "EmployeeSkills")',
             cache: false,
             type: 'POST',
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             data: ko.toJSON({ 'skillName': skillName }),
             success: function (data) {
                 // alert(data.SkillsId) --> alerts expected int value
                 self.SkillsId(data.SkillsId);
                 ko.applyBindings(self.EmployeeSkillsArray);
             }
           }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
             alert(err);
           });
        }

    var viewModel = new EmployeeSkillsViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  });
</script>
```

I have a modal popup that allows the user to enter a value into the input and when they click the btnSaveSkillName the function updateSkillName (above) is called

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="close-editSkillName btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnSaveSkillName" data-bind="click: $root.updateSkillName(ctrl)">Update Skill Name</button>
</div>
```

I pass this value in the skillName property to my controller and return in my response an integer value with the id of the skill name entered.  I would like to update the row of underlying view model with this new integer value but I am not finding an easy way to do so.

Comment: It seems a little unclear what problem you are having. I don't see any attempt to update your array in the code you posted so I can't tell you what's wrong with it. I'm also not sure why you're calling applyBindings on the array that should only be necessary if you're introducing new DOM elements.

Comment: Jason, in the success of the ajax call I am attempting to save to my array the changed data which is only the skillsId.  Maybe applyBindings isn't correct in that place.  This is part of my issue.  I am not sure how to save to the array a change to a property when that value is updated from the database and not the user interface.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the issue then, but it seems like you just need to loop through the array to find the element that needs to be updated, and then set its skillsId to the new skillsId returned in the data. Perhaps make a note of which array item you're trying to update when you make the database call so that when the data comes back you can update that item.

Comment: Yes Jason, how do I do that?  this is at the core of what I am asking.